# Re: .Copy and .Paste in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Why, when copying a cell, shape, etc in Excel VBA, is `ActiveSheet.Cells(i,j).Paste` not valid?

Instead I have

```
Cells(i,j).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

which works, but why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `.Paste` has to be applied to a SheetObject (as you have written correctly: `ActiveSheet.Paste`)

Check out the method on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821951.aspx). It has to be used the following way:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C5").Copy 
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D5")
```

Or more shortly:

```
Cells(j,i).Copy Destination:=Cells(y,z)
```

Or use the [PasteSpecial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff839476.aspx)-method. It can be applied to Range-objects:

```
With sheet
    .Range("C1:C5").Copy 
    .Range("D1:D5").PasteSpecial Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd 
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to tell it to paste for example,
if you have the variables set for i and j then you can use this

```
Range("A1").Copy Cells(i, j)
```

You could even have no copying at all, such as:

```
Cells(i, j)=Range("A1")
```